# How to vectorize calculation of homogenous transformation matrix/tensor?

Tags: for-loop, vectorization, octave, homogenous-transformation

For my simulation I need to calculate many transformation matrices therefore I would like to vectorize a for-loop that I'm using right now.

Is there a way to vectorize the existing for-loop or do I probably need another approach in calculating the vectors and matrices before?

I prepared a little working example:

```matlab
n_dim = 1e5;
p1_3 = zeros(3,n_dim);                          % translationvector (no trans.) [3x100000]
tx = ones(1,n_dim)*15./180*pi;                  % turn angle around x-axis (fixed) [1x100000]
ty = zeros(1,n_dim);                            % turn angle around y-axis (no turn) [1x100000]
tz = randi([-180 180], 1, n_dim)./180*pi;       % turn angle around z-axis (different turn) [1x100000]
hom = [0 0 0 1].*ones(n_dim,4);                 % vector needed for homogenous transformation [100000x4]

% calculate sin/cosin values for rotation [100000x1 each]
cx = cos(tx)';
sx = sin(tx)';

cy = cos(ty)';
sy = sin(ty)';

cz = cos(tz)';
sz = sin(tz)';

% calculate rotation matrix [300000x3]
R_full = [        cy.*cz,         -cy.*sz,     sy; ...
          cx.*sz+sx.*sy.*cz, cx.*cz-sx.*sy.*sz, -sx.*cy; ...
          sx.*sz-cx.*sy.*cz, cz.*sx+cx.*sy.*sz,  cx.*cy];

% prealocate transformation tensor
T = zeros(4,4,n_dim);

% create transformation tensor here
% T = [R11 R12 R13 p1;
%      R21 R22 R23 p2;
%      R31 R32 R33 p3;
%       0   0   0   1]
tic
for i = 1:n_dim           
  T(:,:,i) = [[R_full(i,1), R_full(i,2), R_full(i,3); ...
               R_full(n_dim+i,1), R_full(n_dim+i,2), R_full(n_dim+i,3); ...
               R_full(2*n_dim+i,1), R_full(2*n_dim+i,2), R_full(2*n_dim+i,3)], p1_3(:,i);
               hom(i,:)];
end
toc
```

Comment: Are you using MATLAB or Octave? They are not the same...

Comment: I'm using octave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
T = permute(reshape(R_full,n_dim,3,3),[2,3,1]);
T(4,4,:) = 1;
```

Your method:

```
Elapsed time is 0.839315 seconds.
```

This method:

```
Elapsed time is 0.015389 seconds.
```

Comment: thank you! the permute command is still a bit mysterious to me :D I just had to adjust the index of reshape(), in my example it's n_dim with 100000 instead of 1000 :)

Comment: Whoops, fixed. Thanks! The idea is simple: you had arranged your data as `n_dim*3 x 3`, putting several length-`n_dim` vectors beside each other. Instead, you can arrange it as `n_dim x 3 x 3` in a 3-D matrix. The permute does nothing but switch those dimensions, to make it `3 x 3 x n_dim` instead, as you need it for your `T`. Kind of like a generalization of the matrix transpose, which flips two dimensions in a matrix.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

I included [Florian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55416260/11089932), and of course he wins.

---

Are you ready for some crazy indexing foo? Here we go:

```matlab
clear all;
close all;
clc;

n_dim_max = 200;

t_loop = zeros(n_dim_max, 1);
t_indexing = t_loop;
t_permute = t_loop;

fprintf("---------------------------------------------------------------\n");

for n_dim = 1:n_dim_max

  p1_3 = zeros(3,n_dim);                          % translationvector (no trans.) [3x100000]
  tx = ones(1,n_dim)*15./180*pi;                  % turn angle around x-axis (fixed) [1x100000]
  ty = zeros(1,n_dim);                            % turn angle around y-axis (no turn) [1x100000]
  tz = randi([-180 180], 1, n_dim)./180*pi;       % turn angle around z-axis (different turn) [1x100000]
  hom = [0 0 0 1].*ones(n_dim,4);                 % vector needed for homogenous transformation [100000x4]

  % calculate sin/cosin values for rotation [100000x1 each]
  cx = cos(tx)';
  sx = sin(tx)';

  cy = cos(ty)';
  sy = sin(ty)';

  cz = cos(tz)';
  sz = sin(tz)';

  % calculate rotation matrix [300000x3]
  R_full = [        cy.*cz,         -cy.*sz,     sy; ...
            cx.*sz+sx.*sy.*cz, cx.*cz-sx.*sy.*sz, -sx.*cy; ...
            sx.*sz-cx.*sy.*cz, cz.*sx+cx.*sy.*sz,  cx.*cy];

  % prealocate transformation tensor
  T = zeros(4,4,n_dim);

  % create transformation tensor here
  % T = [R11 R12 R13 p1;
  %      R21 R22 R23 p2;
  %      R31 R32 R33 p3;
  %       0   0   0   1]
  tic
  for i = 1:n_dim           
    T(:,:,i) = [[R_full(i,1), R_full(i,2), R_full(i,3); ...
                 R_full(n_dim+i,1), R_full(n_dim+i,2), R_full(n_dim+i,3); ...
                 R_full(2*n_dim+i,1), R_full(2*n_dim+i,2), R_full(2*n_dim+i,3)], p1_3(:,i);
                 hom(i,:)];
  end
  t_loop(n_dim) = toc;

  tic
  % prealocate transformation tensor
  TT = zeros(4, 4);
  TT(end) = 1;
  TT = repmat(TT, 1, 1, n_dim);

  % Crazy index finding.
  temp = repmat(1:(3*n_dim):(3*3*n_dim), 3, 1) + n_dim .* ((0:2).' * ones(1, 3));
  temp = repmat(temp, 1, 1, n_dim);
  t = zeros(1, 1, n_dim);
  t(:) = 0:(n_dim-1);
  temp = temp + ones(3, 3, n_dim) .* t;

  % Direct assignment using crazily found indices.
  TT(1:3, 1:3, :) = R_full(temp);
  t_indexing(n_dim) = toc;

  tic
  % prealocate transformation tensor
  TTT = zeros(4, 4);
  TTT(end) = 1;
  TTT = repmat(TTT, 1, 1, n_dim);

  TTT(1:3, 1:3, :) = permute(reshape(R_full, n_dim, 3, 3), [2, 3, 1]);
  t_permute(n_dim) = toc;

  % Check
  fprintf("n_dim: %d\n", n_dim);
  fprintf("T equals TT: %d\n", (sum(T(:) == TT(:))) == (4 * 4 * n_dim));
  fprintf("T equals TTT: %d\n", (sum(T(:) == TTT(:))) == (4 * 4 * n_dim));
  fprintf("---------------------------------------------------------------\n");
end

figure(1);
plot(1:n_dim_max, t_loop, 1:n_dim_max, t_indexing, 1:n_dim_max, t_permute);
legend({'Loop', 'Indexing', 'Permute'});
xlabel('Dimension');
ylabel('Elapsed time [s]');
```

[image]

Sorry, the script got lengthy, because it's your initial solution, my solution, (and [Florian's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55416260/11089932)) and testing script all-in-one. Lazy friday was the reason for me not to split things properly...

How did I get there? Simple "reverse engineering". I took your solution for `n_dim = [2, 3, 4]` and determined `[~, ii] = ismember(T(1:3, 1:3, :), R_full)`, i.e. the mapping of `R_full` to `T(1:3, 1:3, :)`. Then, I analyzed the indexing scheme, and found the proper solution to mimic that mapping for arbitrary `n_dim`. Done! ;-) Yes, I like crazy indexing stuff.